# Entity Framework & SQL Compact Edition - how do I get ntext?

Tags: entity-framework, sql-server-ce, ntext

The answer to my question should be quite obvious, but I cannot find it. I have a edmx file that has one table. There is a field of type `string`. EF always generates nvarchar for that (which is kind of expected), but **I need an `ntext` instead of `nvarchar`** for that field as 4000 is too small for me.

**So tell me - what is the proper way to tell EF to generate `ntext` fields?**

PS Using Entity Framework 4, SQL CE 3.5

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess you are using model first, don't you? You can simply create custom T4 template for SQL DDL generation and include logic which will use `NTEXT` when field is defined with max size.

Default template is on:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Common7\IDE\Extensions\Microsoft\Entity Framework Tools\DBGen\SSDLToSQL10.tt
```

Just copy this template and find the logic where data type is created. Once you have your template change DDL Generation Template in model properties (in the designer) to your modified version.

[There is much more you can do](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5912839/how-do-i-use-structural-annotations-to-set-sql-type-to-date-in-model-first-approa/5924143#5924143) with generation template because you can add some annotations to your model (XML) and use them for custom logic in the SQL generation process.

Comment: Thanks @Ladislav, but I don't have a model defined so how can I get the project to use the modified template?

Comment: @Andrew: What do you mean by: *I don't have a model defined*

Comment: @LadislavMrnka: Sorry, I meant to say that my project doesn't contain a .EDMX entity model file or designer. The database is generated from my POCOs using the DbContext and DatabaseInitializer classes from the EF Code First libraries.  I just set a connection string and the database is generated for me.  How can I get the automated database generation to use the custom T4 template?

Answer (score 1):

Just set the property "MaxLength" in the Designer to "Max". This will generate a ntext field in the SQL CE DB.

Answer (score 0):

If your project contains an ADO.Net Entity Data Model (`.edmx`) then see [Ladislav's excellent answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6151083/5662).

But if you're using the **Code First** libraries and your project doesn't contain a `.edmx` then you can use the [`System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.ColumnAttribute`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.columnattribute%28v=vs.103%29.aspx) to specify the column type:

```
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;

public class Note {

    [Column("Note", TypeName="ntext")]
    public string Note { get; set; }

}
```

Comment: Note also that if you're using anything other than SQL CE (e.g. SQL Express or SQL Server), you'll need to replace `TypeName="ntext"` with `TypeName="text"`