# How to add a filestream column in the Entity Framework 4.0 model first designer?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server-2008, entity-framework-4, filestream

I'm using the EF 4.0 designer to create a database by clicking on "Generate Database from Model".
I wan't to use the sql 2008 column type "filestream".
Unfortunately I can't select "filestream" from Type DropDownList of a specific column.

So, how do I use the filestream with EF 4.0 model first?

So far I've googled some SQL scripts to manually add such columns, but adding them via SQL script means that I don't have them in my model. What should I do?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Entity framework doesn't support `Filestream`. Even if you add it, it will still be used as any other `varbinary(max)` column. To use `Filestream` during database generation you must use [custom structural annotation and modify generation template](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5912839/how-do-i-use-structural-annotations-to-set-sql-type-to-date-in-model-first-approa/5924143#5924143).

Answer (score 1):

The varbinary(max) binary large object (BLOB) data is stored as files on the file system. There is not a sql type named FILESTREAM. It is an attribute for BLOB data stored in varbinary(MAX) columns.