# How to access FileTables from Entity Framework?

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework, sql-server-2012, ef-code-first, poco

SQL Server 2012 "Denali" introduced new nice feature [FileTables](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff929144%28v=sql.110%29.aspx)!
I plan to use EF 4.3 Code First.
How to create poco class for FileTable table?
How to access FileTables from Entity Framework except 
 [ObjectContext.ExecuteStoreCommand](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.objects.objectcontext.executestorecommand.aspx)?

Answer (score 1):

Entity Framework does not support FileStream in Sql server 2008 and FileTables in Sql server 2012.

[How to add a filestream column in the Entity Framework 4.0 model first designer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6924698/how-to-add-a-filestream-column-in-the-entity-framework-4-0-model-first-designer)