# DateTime mapping and precision in Entity Framework model-first approach

Tags: entity-framework-4

I would like a **DateTime-property in my model, backed by an MSSQL2008-type that can hold at least 3 milliseconds precision. And I want to do it model-first**, i.e. being able to click "Generate Database from Model..." in the VS2010 designer and get the right result without further tweaking (I know there are numerous workarounds).

---

My own research:
I've seen some other threads on the topic of datetime2 issues, but there the problem seems to be the opposite, getting datetime2 when they want datetime. Solutions are written that suggests ProviderManifestToken="2005" in EDMX gives datetime, while ProviderManifestToken="2008" gives datetime2 behaviour.

I want datetime2 and I already have ProviderManifestToken="2008", but still only get datetime.
There is an [MSDN-thread that's suggesting a manually modifed T4-template](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/eu/adodotnetentityframework/thread/22ee46ca-9b6e-44a4-b5ed-b7e89a68a9b8).
But is tweaking the T4 (or the EDMX-file in a text editor) the only ways of accomplishing datetime2 behaviour in Model First? That's not a nice way of adding precision datetime properties to your EF model...

**Update:**
I have submitted this issue to Microsoft Connect, you can find it [here](http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/705630/entity-framework-ddl-generation-template-for-mssql2008-should-take-precision-into-consideration-when-choosing-db-column-data-type-for-datetime-properties). Vote for it if you want to give it a boost...

Answer (score 3):

Default SQL generation will always use `DATETIME`. If you want to use `DATETIME2` instead you can simply try to generate SQL script from your model and replace `DATETIME` with `DATETIME2` when you need it (it should work). If you want the better control over the generation you really must modify template and you must also manually modify EDMX => structural based annotations. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5912839/how-do-i-use-structural-annotations-to-set-sql-type-to-date-in-model-first-appro/5924143#5924143) is similar answer using `DATE` instead of `DATETIME`.

Comment: Interesting article on how to extend EDMX files. However I was more interested in whether I could get this to work out-of-box. I have now registered my issue at Micorsoft Connect, see my update above.

Comment: I having an issue with precision of DateTime. I tried to manually update the *.edmx file, but seem to have failed. The mapping details for the table has the correct precision. The SProc, unfortunately doesnt. Any ideas why this isnt working? http://imgur.com/PXUmVKN  http://imgur.com/e7BqNwU

Comment: EDIT: Ive managed to manually construct what i need by using the TimeOfDay property. Still not sure why the original DateTime isnt including the subsecond info though.