# Entity Framework 4 - using DateTime2

Tags: sql-server-2008, entity-framework, entity-framework-4

I want Entity Framework to store all my dates as DateTime2 data type.

I have ProviderManifestToken="2008" in my SSDL and still all the generated dates are DateTime instead of DateTime2. What am I missing?

Answer (score 1):

You are not missing anything. Entity framework never uses `DataTime2` unless you manually modify its database generation process (only in model first approach). You need to update SSDLToSQL10.tt file to use `DateTime2` instead of `DateTime`. Check the [end of this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5912839/how-do-i-use-structural-annotations-to-set-sql-type-to-date-in-model-first-appro/5924143#5924143) for more details about modifying the template and configuring VS to use the new template.