# How to define a concurrency property in Model-First

Tags: entity-framework, concurrency, timestamp, ef-model-first

I use Entity Framework Model-First, I want to define a column for concurrency checking. One of my property named Version, I set its Concurrency Mode to 'Fixed', type to 'Binary', 'StoreGeneratedPattern' to 'Computed'. I want the column like timestamp, every time I insert or update, the database auto-generated a value for the record.

But, when I insert records, the Version property is not nullable, so, if I don't assign it a value, the SaveChanges will not work. How can I solve it? Is my solution of creating concurrency property correct?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You can define the column as nullable. Sql server will fill/update it anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your expectations are correct but model first default database creation workflow is not. Current model first workflow never creates `timestamp` columns - it uses just `varbinary`. To force your expected behavior you must modify the workflow which is not an easy task: here is [something related to the topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5912839/how-do-i-use-structural-annotations-to-set-sql-type-to-date-in-model-first-appro/5924143#5924143).