# EDM structural annotations - example xml config for providing IgnoreDataMemberAttribute on a property

Tags: entity-framework-4

Traditional Entity Framework 4 project (not POCOs).

By default, all primitive and navigation entity properties are marked with DataMemberAttribute.

I would like to mark one entity navigation property with IgnoreDataMemberAttribute.  The purpose is so that when using the DataContractSerializer in WCF, it doesn't generate a very large serialized object in web services when there are a large number of related entities in a collection.   The accessibility of the property does not seem to matter.

I've seen some documentation [here](https://blogs.msdn.com/b/efdesign/archive/2008/08/12/structural-annotations-one-pager.aspx) and [here](http://preview.library.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd456856.aspx) about using Structural Annotations with the edmx file.  This would seem to be a good fit for this purpose.

Is it possible to use Structural Annotations to mark an entity property with IgnoreDataMemberAttribute in the CSDL of the edmx file?

If so, can someone provide an example?

Thanks!

Comment: You don't need to mark it with `IgnoreDataMemberAttribute` - it is only needed for default serialization. You just need to remove `DataMemberAttribute` but the point is the same - you need to tell T4 template to not generate the attribute.

Comment: I wrote [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5912839/how-do-i-use-structural-annotations-to-set-sql-type-to-date-in-model-first-appro/5924143#5924143) long time ago. It uses structural annotation for different purpose but you can find there some initial information like defining the annotation and accessing the annotation in the T4 template. You don't need to use `CopyToSSDL` attribute because your annotation is only for CSDL.

Comment: If you want to control the annotation from property window in the designer (instead of XML) you will also have to write extension for Visual Studio.

Answer (score 0):

It would appear that this is possible by using a custom T4 template, although this approach removes the attribute for all Navigation properties.

The steps are:

Right-click on the EDM designer surface, and select Add Code Generation Item.

- Select ADO.NET EntityObject Generator And specify the name of the T4
  template tt file that you are creating.
- Click on the EDMX file in the Solution Explorer window, and in the
  properties pane clear the Custom Tool property.
- Click on the TT file in the Solution Explorer window, and in
  properties pane, specify the Custom Tool Namespace (if applicable).
- Edit the TT file to remove the [DataMemberAttribute] from the Navigation Property  section

More information:

https://blogs.msdn.com/b/efdesign/archive/2009/01/22/customizing-entity-classes-with-t4.aspx

http://www.smartsoftwarebits.com/qaa/46-misc/107-how-to-prevent-entity-framework-navigation-property-from-being-exposed-through-wcf-service